# Toggle injection of context_script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm toying around with Chrome trying to create my first extension. Basically, I want to create a script that does some DOM manipulation on a particular domain. Furthermore, I want the user to be able to toggle the script through an icon displayed in the address bar, when visiting that particular domain.

So far, I've got this manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Ekstrafri",
  "description": "Removes annoying boxes for paid articles.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "Foobar"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://ekstrabladet.dk/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "cleaner.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

`cleaner.js` contains a couple of jQuery DOM selectors that removes some stuff.

The current setup works, but the context script is injected all the time. I want the user to be able to toggle, which should trigger a confirmation prompt in which the user accepts or rejects a page reload.

Anyway, `page_action` doesn't seem to display any icon. According to the documentation, it should display an icon in the address bar.

I have two questions:

1. How do I display this page_action icon on the matched content?
2. How do I bind an event to that icon?

Comment: i dont think you _can_ or _should_ do it via the manifest. A simple `if` inside of content script will do just fine ;)

Comment: @c69 has it right. I actually just finished answering a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174093/how-do-i-toggle-on-off-content-scripts-in-a-google-extension/17184874#17184874

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do here is get and set a variable in a background.js page using the message [passing framework](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). Essentially when the content-script runs you can contact the background script to check the state of a boolean variable. You can then determine whether or not to execute the rest of the script.

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "runScript" }, function (response) {
   if (response == true) {
     //Run the rest of your script inside here...
   }
});
```

You would also use this initial call to bind some UI on the page so you can toggle this state (i.e. switch the content script on/off). In this example I'm using a checkbox.

```
$("chkOnOff").click(function(){

   var scriptOn  = ($(this).is(":checked");

   chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "updateRunScriptState", data: { "scriptOn" : scriptOn  }  }, function (response) {
       //Update confirmed
   });

});
```

The **background.js page** would look something like this:

```
//Global variable in background.js
var scriptOn = true;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "runScript") {
        sendResponse(scriptOn);
    }

    if (request.cmd == "updateRunScriptState") {
        //here we can update the state
         scriptOn = request.data.scriptOn;
    }
});
```

And don't forget to register the background.js page in the manifest.

```
..
  "background": {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },
..
```